# Format JSON with indentation in Go

Tags: json, go

After I do

```
    json, err := json.Marshal(buf)
```

I get something like:

```
{"a":123,"b":"abc"}
```

But what I want is an indented version of this:

```
{
    "a": 123,
    "b": "abc"
}
```

How?

Comment: You want to see it formatted in chrome browser then use JSON Formatter extension.

Comment: use `MarshalIndent`

Comment: @Rakib no, just want to print it to console or save to file

Answer (score 26):

Use `json.MarshalIndent(group, "", "\t")`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/ZNUizMYoFj):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type ColorGroup struct {
        ID     int
        Name   string
        Colors []string
    }
    group := ColorGroup{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Reds",
        Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
    }
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(group, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

output:

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Reds",
    "Colors": [
        "Crimson",
        "Red",
        "Ruby",
        "Maroon"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to have lists of basic types not linebreaked?

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt: You may write Custom JSON Marshalling yourself.

Comment: yes, will become a lot of work =). I also assume it should be possible, with reflect and whatsoever.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt: regexp: `(\[[^[\]]+\])`  Try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/yJ5PVLVVNkL)

Comment: I only want to format lists of basic types...